# Laravel : advanced search form query

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I have an advanced search form to filter out results from a database using Laravel. The data is filtered correctly but I have a requirement for the user to be able to filter by first name or last name using the same text box (in the advanced form). I tried orWhere to make sure it filters the name field with the first name or last name but the orWhere doesn't consider the other filters. The code I am using is as follows:

```
DB::table('mytable')
                ->where(function($query) use ($name, $degree_s, $specialty_s, $city_s, $state_s, $lundbeck_id_s) {

                if ($name)
                    $query->where('first_name', 'like', "$name%")->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "$name%"); # this is whats causing the issue
                if ($specialty_s)
                    $query->where('primary_specialty', $specialty_s);
                if ($city_s)
                    $query->where('city', $city_s);
                if ($state_s)
                    $query->where('state_province', $state_s);
                if ($lundbeck_id_s)
                    $query->where('customer_master_id', $lundbeck_id_s);
                if ($degree_s)
                    $query->where('primary_degree', $degree_s);
                })

                ->select('id', 'first_name','last_name')
```

Adding the orWhere clause causes the query to not use the other conditions as well (like city_s or state_s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change:

```
if ($name)
   $query->where('first_name', 'like', "$name%")->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "$name%");
```

into:

```
if ($name) {
   $query->where(function($q) use ($name) {
         $q->where('first_name', 'like', "$name%")->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "$name%");
   });
}
```

to make Laravel to add parentheses so it will work as you expect.

**EDIT**

Of course you don't need to wrap everything with closure here, so the best solution for that would be:

```
<?php

$query = DB::table('mytable')->select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name');

if ($name) {
    $query->where(function ($q) use ($name) {
        $q->where('first_name', 'like', "$name%")
            ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "$name%");
    });
}
if ($specialty_s) {
    $query->where('primary_specialty', $specialty_s);
}
if ($city_s) {
    $query->where('city', $city_s);
}
if ($state_s) {
    $query->where('state_province', $state_s);
}
if ($lundbeck_id_s) {
    $query->where('customer_master_id', $lundbeck_id_s);
}
if ($degree_s) {
    $query->where('primary_degree', $degree_s);
}

$data = $query->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcin, this was the solution I had implemented

Comment: What about pagination?

Comment: see also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544842/laravel-advanced-search

Answer (score 2):

i will build the query little bit differently.

```
$q = DB::table('mytable')->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);

if(!empty($name))
{
    $q->where(function($query)use($name){
        $query->where(('first_name', 'like', "$name%")
              ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', "$name%");
    });
}

if(!empty($specialty_s) $q->where('primary_specialty', $specialty_s);
```

so far.... so forth.

at last

return `q->get()` or `$q->paginate(30)` depending upon your needs.

Comment: It won't work as expected. It will create query `where A or B AND C`

Comment: You also forgot here about adding `use ($name)` to your closure

Comment: having a bad day.... my mind is in stackoverflow i guess argh.... thank you for the corrections. again :)