# laravel advanced search

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to make an advanced search in which the user has optional parameters to search,am joining data from three tables as follows

```
$qry="SELECT rooms.*, salereservation.*, customers.*
                FROM rooms
                    JOIN salereservation
                        ON salereservation.room_id = rooms.room_id
                    JOIN customers
                        ON customers.id = salereservation.customer_id
                WHERE salereservation.sale_status=1 AND ";
```

i am appending to the query string the optional parameters as follows

```
if($fname!=''){
        $qry.="fname LIKE %fname% AND ";
    }
    if($lname!=''){
        $qry.="lname LIKE %:lname% AND ";
    }
    if($time_in!=''){
        $qry.="start_datetime LIKE %time_in% AND ";
    }
    if($time_out!=''){
        $qry.="end_datetime LIKE %time_out% AND ";
    }
    if($phone!=''){
        $qry.="phone LIKE %phone% AND ";
    }
    if($room_no!=''){
        $qry.="room_no LIKE %room_no%";
    }
```

my problem is how to turn the code into laravel query builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try this code but its should work under laravel 4.2.

```
$query = DB::table('rooms')
        ->join("salereservation", "salereservation.room_id", "=", "rooms.room_id")
        ->join("customers", "customers.id", "=", "salereservation.customer_id")
        ->where("salereservation.sale_status",'=',1)
        ->select('rooms.*', 'salereservation.*', 'customers.*');

if($fname!=''){
    $query->where("fname",'like',"%$fname%");
}

if($lname!=''){
    $query->where("lname",'like',"%$lname%");
}
if($time_in!=''){
   $query->where("start_datetime",'like',"%$time_in%");
}
if($time_out!=''){
    $query->where("end_datetime",'like',"%$time_out%");
}
if($phone!=''){
    $query->where("phone",'like',"%$phone%");
}
if($room_no!=''){
  $query->where("room_no",'like',"%$room_no%");
}
$data = $query->get(); //finally get the result
```

**Update:**

For query verification you can print your query using:

```
 $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
 $last_query = end($queries);
 dd($last_query);
```

And verify if your query different from your desired query.
If something went to different we can upgrade our query structure according to them.and also can you update with your latest query generated from laravel methods.

But if you still face some difficulties to understand my point of view. let me know.

Comment: I get empty results if a search anything even if its in the db

Comment: now we can manage our query just concatenation required functioned with $query object, if something running according to plan.

Comment: @safoor Safdar yah the query is exacly like my desired query

Comment: well, good to see, so main concern will be here your desired raw query are good to run to generate desired result or not. could you confirm that?

Comment: 'select `rooms`.*, `salereservation`.*, `customers`.* from `rooms` inner join `salereservation` on `salereservation`.`room_id` = `rooms`.`room_id` inner join `customers` on `customers`.`id` = `salereservation`.`customer_id` where `salereservation`.`sale_status` = ? and `phone` like ?'

Comment: when i input for example the name,it does not look like its appending the name to the query

Comment: can you notice single quote surrounding variable under where method. variable can not place its value under single comma, you have to place with double quote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71036/discussion-between-malouda-and-safoor-safdar).

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your DB like this:

```
rooms:
 - id
 - room_no

reservations:
 - customer_id
 - start_datetime
 - end_datatime
 - room_id

customers:
 - lname
 - fname
 - phone
```

Then setup the propers relationships in your models

```
//Reservation model
class Reservation extends \Eloquent {

    public function room()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Room', 'room_id');
    }

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Customer', 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

Create a query scope like the following :

```
// Reservation model
// $terms is an array which pairs column_name to the querying value
public function scopeSearch($query, $terms)
{
    if ( ! empty($terms['room_no']))
    {
        $query->has('rooms.room_no', $terms['room_no']);
    }

    $customer_cols = ['lname', 'fname', 'phone'];
    $reservations_cols = ['start_datetime', 'end_datetime'];
    foreach ($terms as $key => $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $customer_cols))
        {
            $query->whereHas('customer', function($subquery) use ($key, $value)
            {
                $subquery->where($key, 'like', '%'.$value.'%');
            });
        }
        if (in_array($key, $reservation_cols))
        {
            $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }

}
```

Now you can invoke your query scope by doing the following:

```
$reservations = Reservation:search(array('fname' => 'value', 'lname' => 'value2', ...));
```

And accessing results by:

```
foreach ($reservations as $res)
{
    $res->room->number;
    $res->customer->name;
}
```