# Laravel advanced search guide

Tags: laravel

I would like to ask your suggestions about laravel advanced search, currently I'm working on e-commerce website where i need to make search form which user could choose any field in the form including `price range` or `category` or `brands` etc. and get the results back.

Now my question is what do you suggest that I use [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout) or make custom function such as code below and extend it?

```
$query = DB::table('rooms')
        ->join("salereservation", "salereservation.room_id", "=", "rooms.room_id")
        ->join("customers", "customers.id", "=", "salereservation.customer_id")
        ->where("salereservation.sale_status",'=',1)
        ->select('rooms.*', 'salereservation.*', 'customers.*');

if($fname!=''){
    $query->where("fname",'like',"%$fname%");
}

if($lname!=''){
    $query->where("lname",'like',"%$lname%");
}
if($time_in!=''){
   $query->where("start_datetime",'like',"%$time_in%");
}
if($time_out!=''){
    $query->where("end_datetime",'like',"%$time_out%");
}
if($phone!=''){
    $query->where("phone",'like',"%$phone%");
}
if($room_no!=''){
  $query->where("room_no",'like',"%$room_no%");
}
$data = $query->get(); //finally get the result
```

Obviously code above is not with options i need [- Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544842/laravel-advanced-search)

Please help me to make the right decision.

> PS: database of this application will be massive so I need something to work with big database.

Thank you.

Comment: You could use a something like https://www.algolia.com/ ...

Comment: @Serge I'm looking to making things not to use algilia.

Answer (score 2):

There are some options i'm gonna describe them for you :
1-Simple eloquent( or raw) queries in laravel, it's not awefull but it has it's downsides like the code is messy and performance is not great and so is the UX .
2- There's algolia , it's user friendly , easy to setup but it's pretty expensive( believe me i know ) .
3- Lastly use ELASTICSEARCH , it's a search engine like algolia but with cheater pricing and more options and you can config it how ever you want .

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can use laravel **scout** if your functionality is heavy. or if you make normal functionality than you can use your **costume** function. now your choices which can you use ?