# Non functional laravel filter

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to create an items filter based on user selections. The filter works with `GET` and fetches it's parameters from the url.
I tried using the laravel's `when` function but the filter is not working, it keeps returning the same result set without adhering to the filtration rule I wrote for it.

I am on Laravel 8 and I used the method outlined on [Laravel's Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses).

I feel like the problem is with the `whereBetween` clause between even after hard coding values into it, the result was the same as before.

Any help to fix this is greatly appreciated in advance.

```
$queryString = $request->query();
$sortBy = null;
$minMaxArray = array();

if($queryString){
  if (array_key_exists('sortby', $queryString)) {
    $sortBy = ($queryString['sortby'] == 'lowest') ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
  }

  if (array_key_exists('min', $queryString) || array_key_exists('max', $queryString)) {
    $minMaxArray['min'] = preg_replace("/,/", '', $queryString['min']) ?: 0;
    $minMaxArray['max'] = preg_replace("/,/", '', $queryString['max']) ?: 1000000;
  }

}

      $tutors = DB::table('users')
              ->join('tutors', 'users.email', '=', 'tutors.tutorEmail')
              ->where([
                  ['users.name', 'like', '%' . trim($searchText) . '%'],
                  ['tutors.tutorStrength', '<>', '-'],
                  ['users.status', 'active'],
                  ['users.gender', '<>', '-'],
                  ['users.phone', '<>', '-'],
                  ['users.role', 'tutor']
                ])
              ->orWhere([
                ['tutors.tutorStrength', 'like', '%' . trim($searchText) . '%'],
                ['users.status', 'active'],
                ['users.gender', '<>', '-'],
                ['users.phone', '<>', '-'],
                ['users.role', 'tutor'],
              ])
              ->orWhere([
                ['users.location', 'like', '%' . trim($searchText) . '%'],
                ['tutors.tutorStrength', '<>', '-'],
                ['users.status', 'active'],
                ['users.gender', '<>', '-'],
                ['users.phone', '<>', '-'],
                ['users.role', 'tutor'],
              ])
              ->when($minMaxArray, function ($subQuery) use ($minMaxArray){
                return $subQuery->whereBetween('tutors.tutorFee', $minMaxArray);
              })
              ->when($sortBy, function ($subQuery) use ($sortBy){
                return $subQuery->orderBy('tutors.tutorFee', $sortBy);
              }, function ($subQuery){
                return $subQuery->inRandomOrder();
              })
              ->select('tutors.tutorFee', 'tutors.feeType', 'tutors.tutorOccupation', 'tutors.tutorStrength', 'users.*')->distinct()->paginate(20);
```

Comment: this is wrong for search function you need to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972963/laravel-advanced-search-form-query

Comment: Hi @KamleshPaul, I tried the solution on the link but it didn't work. I forgot to add that I am using laravel 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Turned out that I needed to duplicate the `when` conditional clauses on each `where` and `orWhere` clause.

I appreciate [Kamlesh Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10834466/kamlesh-paul) for trying to help.